# place marker on polyline with specific distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have made a google map using google map api v3 and placed a polyline on map here is my code for my map

```
function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.77577, 72.26588);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.77577, 72.26588),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.75715, 72.25918),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.7379, 72.2415),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.717362, 72.226646),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.720063, 72.216905),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.714514, 72.206905),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.7086, 72.186735),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.702685, 72.177294)

  ];
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });

            flightPath.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Now i want to Place marker on this polyline on each 1 km.Please any one help to place marker on 1km on polyline.

Comment: [example with markers every 2 km](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html), uses a ported version of Mike Williams' epoly library, probably can be done with the Google Maps API v3 geometry library as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (added to the end of your initialize function):

```
var i=1;
var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(flightPath.getPath());
var remainingDist = length;

while (remainingDist > 0)
{
   createMarker(map, flightPath.GetPointAtDistance(1000*i),i+" km");
   remainingDist -= 1000;
   i++;
}
// put markers at the ends
createMarker(map,flightPath.getPath().getAt(0),length/1000+" km");
createMarker(map,flightPath.getPath().getAt(flightPath.getPath().getLength()-1),(length/1000).toFixed(2)+" km");
flightPath.setMap(map);
}

function createMarker(map, latlng, title){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:latlng,
          map:map,
          title: title
          });
}
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_kmmarkers.html)