# Get exact geo coordinates along an entire route, Google Maps or OpenStreetMap

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, openstreetmap

Suppose I have a route defined from one town to another.  From the Google Maps API I can recover a route between the two.  However, the route returned from Google is a driving route that includes geo-coordinates only at places where there is another step in a leg (for example, where I have to turn from one highway to another).

What I need is geo-locations (lat/long) along the entire route, at specific intervals (for example, every 1/4 mile or 100m).

Is there a way to accomplish this via the Google Maps API / web services?

Or would the OpenStreetMap database be the way to do it?

Kind regards,
Madeleine.

Comment: Are you trying to make "mile markers"? Like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705895/place-marker-on-polyline-with-specific-distance/16706394#16706394) or [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)

Comment: Yes, something like mile markers is what I'm after.  The geocodzip link is very helpful.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[OSRM](http://osrm.at/) gives you routes with road geometries as they are in the OpenStreetMap database. For example, you can get the route as GPX (and post-process this file if you want). This would look like the following:

```
GET http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?hl=en&loc=47.064970,15.458470&loc=47.071100,15.476760&output=gpx
```

Read more: [OSRM API docs](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Server-api).

Comment: Is there something similar for paths or trails?

Comment: The query above does not work anymore since the "viaroute" service of OSRM was replaced by the "route" service.
See my answer for a current solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539464/2350644

Answer (score 14):

Since the accepted answer is outdated and does not work anymore, here is how all nodes along a road can be queried using the [route service](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.10.0/api/#route-service) from [Project OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/).

Given an arbitrary number of lon,lat pairs.
For Instance the following three (in Berlin):

- 13.388860,52.517037
- 13.397634,52.529407
- 13.428555,52.523219

The route-service calculates the fastest route between these points and its possible to return all nodes along the road using the following query:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?alternatives=false&annotations=nodes
```

This returns a json response containing node IDs of all the nodes along the route. The result should look something like this:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      ...
      "legs": [
        {
          "annotation": {
            "nodes": [
              2264199819,
              2045820592,
              21487242,
              ...
    ]
 }
```

To receive the lat,lon coordinates of the nodes [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) can be used.

```
[out:json];
(
   node(264199819);
   node(...);
   node(...);
   ...
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

Here is a sample request using overpass-turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/toe

Comment: I have source and destination lat-lng pair and I want the lat-lng pairs for intermediate points which are not far by say 20 miles. How do I achieve that?

Comment: When I use the OverpassAPI to get the lats and lngs, I get a json that is sorted by node_id. But I want the json sorted as same as the order of nodes in my query. Do you have any idea, whether I can get it right?

Comment: Whilst this does indeed work, it requires another API request, which uses data unnecessarily and can be slow (I made an 8 second request extremely easily). I'd recommend the answer by @Adithya Ajith, because it is almost instant.

Answer (score 6):

It's simply google.maps.DirectionsService().route() method. You need to pass the service request and then a callback which executes upon completion of the service request.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: Looking at it. But does it give the lat.long between a "leg", say, which is larger than 10 miles ?

Answer (score 5):

While not used as API, here: https://www.nmeagen.org/ one can create "Multi-point line", set the distance between points and download route (coordinates) as CSV.

Comment: I was looking for something exactly like this! I imported the CSV file into the project and can draw any custom line I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the Marlio's answer.

You can use Google Maps Directions API itself.
For a given origin and destination, in the JSON output, look for following:

```
"polyline" : {
  "points" : ""
}
```

You can use a decoder to get the coordinates from the polyline.:
https://github.com/emcconville/google-map-polyline-encoding-tool
Or. you can use the googleway package in R to decode the same.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/googleway.pdf

I am not sure how to set the resolution to your desired level though.But the resolution in the API output is really good.

Comment: Actually, you'll want to get the `overview_polyline` to get all the lat/lon coordinates for the entire route. The [vignette](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/vignettes/googleway-vignette.Rmd) gives more examples & detail.

Comment: But the overview does not trace the curvature of the road precisely.The polyline points for each step in the legs give more detailed route coordinates.

Comment: In my opinion using each of the individual `polyline : points` results in a lot of redundant information (for example the last coordinate of one leg will be the start of the next). Whereas the `overview_polyline` has a point for every change of direction along a road & route, and all the points in between are therefore on a straight line and can be inferred.